# Когда следует начинать пользоваться Google Search Console?

Tags: seo

На каком этапе после того, как новосозданный сайт размещён в интернете, с точки зрения SEO лучше регистрировать его в Google Search Console?

Answer (score 3):

**Чем раньше, тем лучше**.

Подтвердив право на владение, выполняйте рекомендации [Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=ru) и исправляйте ошибки в случае, если таковые найдутся. Тем быстрее сайт выйдет на высокие позиции в ранжировании Google. Промедлите — так эти ошибки и невыполнение рекомендаций Вам аукнутся помехами продвижению сайта.

Не следует откладывать в долгий ящик и регистрацию в [Яндекс.Вебмастере](https://webmaster.yandex.ru/), да и кабинетами от [Mail.ru](http://webmaster.mail.ru/) и [Bing](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/) желательно не пренебрегать.

О действиях, выполняемых в этих вебмастерах, см. [здесь](http://www.tehpodderzka.ru/2015/11/webmaster.html). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Чем быстрее, тем лучше.
Статистика начинает собираться с момента регистрации и подтверждения прав на ресурс.
Чем быстрее это сделать, тем больше данных у вас будет предоставлено для дальнейшей работы.